# Manually create new log file with CocoaLumberjack

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

I have configure CocoaLumberjack like this:

```
// CocoaLumberjack
DDLog.add(DDASLLogger.sharedInstance, with: DDLogLevel.debug)
DDLog.add(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance, with: DDLogLevel.debug)
DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance.colorsEnabled = true
fileLogger = DDFileLogger.init()
fileLogger?.doNotReuseLogFiles = true // Always create a new log file when apps starts
fileLogger?.rollingFrequency = 86400 // 24 Hours
fileLogger?.maximumFileSize = 0 // Force log to only roll after 24 hours
fileLogger?.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 1 // Keeps 1 log file plus active log file
DDLog.add(fileLogger!, with: DDLogLevel.debug)
```

In my app, I'll want to have the following log system:

The entry point to my app is a Login View Controller. I want to write log entries here so I can see if everything goes okey. If the user login correctly, I want to roll/archive that log and create a new one for that user. In this new log, I'll keep errors that occurs during user session. If users logout, I want to again roll/archive the log and create a new one. Before rolling/archiving the log I always send it to my server, so I can delete it from the device.

I'm trying the following to roll/archive the log but I'm not succecing:

```
Server().sendUserLog(filePath: DDFileLogger().currentLogFileInfo.filePath, onSuccess: { // This function send the log to the server, if all goes good, I want to roll it. 
          print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> \(DDFileLogger().currentLogFileInfo.filePath)")
          DDFileLogger().rollLogFile(withCompletion: { 
            print("Log rolled")
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> \(DDFileLogger().currentLogFileInfo.filePath)")
          })
        }, onError: { (error) in
          DDLogError("LoginVC - sendUserLog Error: \(error)")
        })
```

Both print, before roll function and after roll function, print the same path and file name. So I'm not creating a new log file.

How can I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new `DDFileLogger` by using `DDFileLogger()`. You should store your fileLogger somewhere and call rollLogFile on the same instance.
Something like this:

```
let fileLogger = DDFileLogger()
Server().sendUserLog(
    filePath: fileLogger.currentLogFileInfo.filePath, 
    onSuccess: { // This function send the log to the server, if all goes good, I want to roll it. 
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> \(fileLogger.currentLogFileInfo.filePath)")
        fileLogger.rollLogFile(withCompletion: { 
            print("Log rolled")
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> \(fileLogger.currentLogFileInfo.filePath)")
        })
    }, 
    onError: { (error) in
      DDLogError("LoginVC - sendUserLog Error: \(error)")
    })
```

Comment: Solved. After reading your answer I feel really stupid, but now it is solved. Thanks @marosoaie